# Can't bind to 'dateClass' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-datepicker' in angular7

Tags: angular-material

I am using angular material date picker in my app.I need to change color of some speccific dates.For this I am using 'dateClass' property of mat-datepicker.But it's not working.

**html**

```
    <mat-datepicker  [dateClass]="dateClass" #picker1 ></mat-datepicker>
```

**component**

```
dateClass = (d: Date) => {
    const date = d.getDate();

    // Highlight the 1st and 20th day of each month.
    return (date === 1 || date === 20) ? 'example-custom-date-class' : undefined;
  }
```

**error**

```
Can't bind to 'dateClass' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-datepicker'.
1. If 'mat-datepicker' is an Angular component and it has 'dateClass' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-datepicker' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you import `MatDatepickerModule`? Also, you need Angular Material version 7.1.0 or later, `dateClass` was introduced in that version.

Comment: how can i update angular material?my current version is 7.0.2

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47760057/4606040) post, `npm update --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For other people facing the same issue (repeating what is mentioned in the comments), make sure you have **at least Angular Material version 7.1.0 or later** installed. Additionally make sure you have imported `MatDatepickerModule`.

To update your Angular Material version use `npm update --save @angular/material @angular/cdk`.